# search for select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, search

I have a rails app where user can assign task to another user by creating task action. At the moment I have the f.collection_select, but as the number of users grows it won't be a good solution. I would like to change it into kinda search form. My problem is that I don't see how I can do this. I have other search forms, but those are for show/index action. How can I do this for the create action?

here is my current code:

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @task]) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'layouts/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :executor_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:executor_id, User.all, :id, :email, class: "form-control") %>
  </div>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :deadline %>
    <%= f.date_select :deadline, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create Task", class: 'btn btn-primary', "data-sid" => current_user.id, "data-rip" => :executor_id %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You could try some gems which will do the work for you. For example: https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: Or you could just build a search form yourself send a Get to a `search` action in the users_controller which will receive the param you send (I don't know what you want to search by, user name? email?) then delegate the user model where you will implement the logic needed to find the user requested.

Comment: Cyzanfar, I would like to be able to search based on name and company, but I have those in the profile model as :first_name, :last_name and :company. user has_one profile. How would you do this for multiple attributes like this?

Comment: take a look at the [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) documentation.